# Method returns early and unexpectedly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a game with Unity, C# and Visual Studio.

There's a method that had been working correctly, and for an unknown reason it doesn't any more. By using Visual Studio's Code Stepping I found out that the method returns immediately after it finishes the if code block.

That means that the lines

```
equippedItem = null;
slotIsEquipped = false;
```

doesn't get executed any more.

```
    public void Unequip()
{
    if (equippedItem != null)
    {
        equippedItem.transform.parent = null;
        equippedItem.GetComponent<Animator>().applyRootMotion = true;
        equippedItem.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        equippedItem.transform.position = new Vector3(0, -256, 0);
        equippedItem.GetComponent<Weapon>().holder = null; //
    }
    equippedItem = null;
    slotIsEquipped = false;
}
```

How on Earth is this possible ?

Comment: Are you running in Release mode?

Comment: Nope, the settings are Debug / Any CPU.

Comment: If you put something directly after `equippedItem.GetComponent<Weapon>().holder = null;`, will it execute?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't. And I just noticed that in Unity's console an error message appeared about a null reference. "holder" was null prior to the method making it null, and the method was failing silently. I expect to see errors on VS but it looks like some errors are showing up only on Unity and others only on VS, which makes debugging a harder process. Your input was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the method was returning early was because in the final line of the **if** code block the method *GetComponent()* was returning **null**, something that couldn't be seen through Visual Studio, but only through Unity3D. The method was failing silently without any error appearing in Visual Studio, or app crash as it is usual with standard programs like WinForms, thus I had no idea *GetComponent()* was failing, until *IllidanS4* pointed me to check if anything else executes if placed right under the failing line. Once I knew which line had the problem, finding the reason and fixing the problem was easy.

Comment: Did you try with adding try-catch block?

Comment: Not really. Good question. For some reason although I'd put almost all of my code at try-catch blocks when I was working on winforms, I've never used them on my work with Unity3D. I forgot them. I guess it's because I got used to Unity's debug logger so much I ended relying too much on it.

Comment: exception handling is good way to log your error and inspect error message in more detail way

Comment: For the record, it is possible to debug in VS using breakpoint. Then you can run the project line by line and see the value given to all the variables. Then you could have seen your variable being null.

Comment: That was how I was debugging, I already know that. The thing is hovering the mouse pointer over the variable on the left part of the = sign wasn't showing its value. I even clicked the "Add Watch" option, and I was getting the message that the variable is out of scope.